# Registering two different types of users

Tags: laravel

I can't sign the user up as either a restaurant or a consumer.

I'm using Laravels built in register and log in templates. However I need to modify the sign up form to include a type. Also using migrations and seeders.

migration

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

seeder

```
DB::table('users')->insert([
    'name' => "admin",
    'email' => 'admin@test.com',
    'password' => bcrypt('admin'),
    // 'type' => true
]);
```

When the user clicks register, a checkbox? will be included for the user to specify the type. If the user is registered as a restaurant, certain permissions are granted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, all depending on complexity.  Typically I do something as such:

I would create a roles table;

Then create a many to many relationship between user and role.

upon creation of a user I  would then assign the relationship of the given role in a (user) class method like:

```
public function giveRole(Role $role) {
     $this->attach($role);
     return true;
}
```

Then on an action that needs a role do a check with:

```
public function hasRole(Role $role) {
    if($this->user->roles()->where('name', $role->name)->get()){
            return true;
     } else {
            return false;
     }
```

But for expandability and convention as well as fewer checks I would go with something like a Gate as seen here :

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization

This still utilizes some of the above code but enforces it globally and only allowing specific routes access based on auth level.

You could use a mixture of both where a show() function may show something different for a different auth level with a hasRole() check and returns a different response.  Or you could block entire routes with the same check using a Gate.  It all depends on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can add fields to the registration page as documented here: [customize-laravel-registration](https://laraveldaily.com/9-things-you-can-customize-in-laravel-registration/)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a field such as is_admin (bit type) to check whether the user is of type 1 or 2.